# Extended Python, how to handle enum

Tags: python

I am writing a wrapper routine using extended python concepts, I am not sure how to handle enums. Basically i have a c function that takes one of the input is enum. What format option should I have to use?

```
typedef enum
{
    ISOUTPUT = 'W',
    ISINPUT = 'R'
} myenum;

int func1( i int, b myenum)
```

my wrapper routine:

```
static PyObject *Wrapper_func1(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int x, result;
    myenum y;    
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"iC",x,y);
    result= func1(x, y);
    return Py_BuildValue("i",result);   
}
```

in the python script

```
import mymodule

x= mymodule.func1(1,'R') --- giving attribute error, when I debugged I found it is giving segment violation,
```

bt:

```
#0  convertsimple (arg=0x73e960, p_format=0x7fffffffd348,
    p_va=<value optimized out>, flags=0,
    msgbuf=0x7fffffffd1b0 "\310V\266\252\252*", bufsize=256,
    freelist=0x7fffffffd330) at Python/getargs.c:684
#1  0x000000000048e30f in convertitem (freelist=<value optimized out>,
    bufsize=<value optimized out>, msgbuf=<value optimized out>,
    levels=<value optimized out>, flags=<value optimized out>,
    p_va=<value optimized out>, p_format=<value optimized out>, arg=0x73e960)
    at Python/getargs.c:499
#2  vgetargs1 (freelist=<value optimized out>, bufsize=<value optimized out>,
    msgbuf=<value optimized out>, levels=<value optimized out>,
    flags=<value optimized out>, p_va=<value optimized out>,
    p_format=<value optimized out>, arg=0x73e960) at Python/getargs.c:330
#3  0x000000000048ea68 in PyArg_ParseTuple (args=0x73e960, format=0x0)
    at Python/getargs.c:102
```

Comment: You could obtain an enum class, if you'd like? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum

Comment: How large is `myenum`? That is, what does `sizeof` against it result in?

Comment: @Dana: That's not actually the problem here.

Comment: I am confused, its just a single byte char

Comment: I found the problem, I have to pass the adress PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"iC",&x,&y);